# Pointtype command for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having trouble using the pointtype command on gnuplot. I've tried several ways such as:

```
set pt 5
set pointtype 5
plot " " w pt 5
plot " " w pointtype 5
```

And for some reason nothing seems to work. I tried using the "help" feature, and apparently my version of gnuplot doesn't have "pt" or "pointtype" as an option. Is this perhaps listed as some other feature. I know the points are there, when I plot multiple sets of data, the point type automatically changes, but I have no personal control over choosing the point type.

Answer (score 62):

You first have to tell Gnuplot to use a style that uses points, e.g. `with points` or `with linespoints`. Try for example:

```
plot sin(x) with points
```

Output:

[image]

Now try:

```
plot sin(x) with points pointtype 5
```

Output:

[image]

You may also want to look at the output from the `test` command which shows you the capabilities of the current terminal. Here are the capabilities for my pngairo terminal:

[image]

Comment: first : show terminal, then test terminal MyTerminal